# onscreen keyboard on login

Tags: release-loki, settings, greeter

Please tell me there is a way to enable onscreen keyboard during login? It used to be in Freya but Loki has many basic things either hidden or just impossible to do anymore?

Please how can I enable it on the login screen as well.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is [an open issue on Githb](https://github.com/elementary/greeter/issues/72) asking for this. Also I'm pretty sure I request this on launchpad when was still possible to report issues there.